# C++ Dynamic array has not requested size

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code

While creating a custom class for STL Multimap, I came across an unintended behaviour where dynamic arrays created by new operator are not of the size between []. In the following code, in `a.Set(3, 'c')` the arrays stored in `newKey` and `newSize` are of size one, when they should have size two. Using the debugger shows that in that lines `index` is equal to 1, so size should be two. Program does not produce any exception but it also does not output the expected result `c`.

As clarification, using the debugger shows that the problem occurs while setting the value at index 1 in `newKey, newSize, newValue`. It does not throw any kind of exception, but does not change any value either.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void Copy(T const* _source, T* _destiny, unsigned long _size)
{
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        _destiny[i] = _source[i];
    }
}
template<typename T>
void CopyNew(T const* _source, T* _destiny, unsigned long _size)
{
    T* target = new T[_size];
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        target[i] = _source[i];
    }
    _destiny = target;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Multimap
{
public:
    Multimap() {}
    unsigned long Get(T1 const& _key, T2** _return)
    {
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < this->keySize_; i++)
        {
            if (_key == this->key_[i])
            {
                CopyNew<T2>(this->value_[i], *_return, this->valueSize_[i]);
                return i;
            }
        }
        *_return = 0;
        return this->keySize_;
    }
    unsigned long Get(T1 const& _key)
    {
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < this->keySize_; i++)
        {
            if (_key == this->key_[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return this->keySize_;    
    }
    int Set(T1 const& _key, T2 const& _value)
    {
        T2* target;
        unsigned long index = this->Get(_key, &target);
        if (target == 0)
        {
            T1* newKey = new T1[index + 1];
            unsigned long* newSize = new unsigned long[index + 1];
            T2** newValue = new T2*[this->keySize_ + 1];
            if (this->keySize_ != 0)
            {
                Copy(this->key_, newKey, index);
                delete[] this->key_;
                Copy(this->valueSize_, newSize, index);
                for (unsigned long i = 0; i < this->keySize_; i++)
                {
                    newValue[i] = new T2[this->valueSize_[i]];
                    Copy(this->value_[i], newValue[i], this->valueSize_[i]);
                    delete[] this->value_[i];
                }
                delete[] this->valueSize_;
            }
            newKey[index] = _key;
            newSize[index] = 0;
            this->key_ = newKey;
            this->valueSize_ = newSize;
            this->value_ = newValue;
            this->keySize_++;
        }
        unsigned long newSize = this->valueSize_[index]+1;
        T2* newValue = new T2[newSize];
        Copy(this->value_[index], newValue, newSize-1);
        newValue[newSize-1] = _value;
        this->valueSize_[index] = newSize;
        this->value_[index] = newValue;
        return newSize;
    }
    unsigned int GetSize()
    {
        return this->keySize_;
    }
protected:
    unsigned long keySize_ = 0;
    unsigned long* valueSize_ = 0;
    T1* key_ = 0;
    T2** value_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Multimap<int, char> a;
    a.Set(2, 'b');
    a.Set(3, 'c');
    char* b;
    a.Get(3, &b);
    std::cout << b[0];
}
```

Comment: Check what happens when you compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and [run tine program](https://godbolt.org/z/jjxfPxToj). Unrelated: "_destiny" should probably be "_destination".

Comment: Side note: explicit use of `new` and `delete` since C++11 is considered as a bad practice. Use `std::vector` or smart pointers. This is more important then learn how to write own templates.

Comment: Whoever wrote `CopyNew` doesn't understand how arguments are by-value unless specified as reference types. `_destiny = target;` means *nothing* to the caller of `CopyNew`. Whatever was provided to `CopyNew` as the `_destiny` argument will remain as it was prior (and as a bonus, `CopyNew` therefore leaks memory to add salt in the wound).

Comment: @MarekR but I heard that using any STL class or function is bad practice since if used in a DLL, STL version of someone using the DLL might be different from the one used to compile the DLL...

Comment: @WhozCraig is considered by-value if argument is a pointer? I read that the only difference between a pointer and a reference is that the reference does not need ```*``` to access the value

Comment: With a DLL you typically need to be as dumb as possible. Anything in the Standard Library could change between library implementations and versions of those implementations. With a DLL you typically want to stick to C.

Comment: @Salty27 Whomever said that was dumbing down the language to the point of bordering on the naive. `_destiny = target;` doesn't change what is being pointed to (by dereference). It changes the value stored in the `_destiny` pointer itself. And since that pointer is just a *value* copy provided to the function from the caller, it changes *nothing* on the caller-side; all its changing is the local variable in the function. If you want the caller's pointer changed, change the argument type to `T* &`

Comment: @user4581301 I am doing a DLL with a lot of classes and inheritance. I heard that is quite harder to do in C, since it is not object oriented, so I am sticking to C++

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the explanation! I think it was in another Stack Overflow thread where I saw that, so I just supposed it would be true

Comment: C++ classes can have a lot of hidden machinery and practically no guarantees about how stable it will be across versions. Compiler implementers generally try to keep things the same from revision to revision, but there's only so much you can do. But different compilers is another matter. So say you have class `X` that's part of an inheritance hierarchy. Your DLL will expect the `X` objects it receives to have a particular size and shape, member variables of a particular size and alignment, a hidden V-Table, and other back end magic that you hope you'll never have to work with directly.

Comment: And then your DLL is called by a program compiled by compiler Q. Q uses different  back end magic, and the `X` instances it sends to your DLL are a different shape. Ka-boom. This may not be a problem for you. Perhaps you only support one compiler and one compiler version. Otherwise your interface needs to only deal in what we used to call Plain Old Data, Trivial types with [Standard Layout.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)

Comment: @user4581301 however, I think my code uses no syntax or functions from a particular compiler, so creating a DLL that works for other compiler would only require to compile it again with the other compiler. This way, it can be used in different compilers and does not require to be compiled if STL gets updated

Comment: It's not the syntax or visible functions. For a simple example, you said you are using inheritance. The C++ Standard specifies how inheritance must behave, but It says almost nothing about how it must be implemented. Where in the object is the book-keeping (probably a V-Table, but what if one of the compilers uses something different?) necessary to manage polymorphism? Is it at the beginning of the object? at the end of the object? How is it organized? If you don't know and can't guarantee it's the same in both the DLL and the caller, you can't safely expose polymorphic classes.

Answer (score -1):

`CopyNew` argument `_destiny` should be `T*&` (as pointed out by WhozCraig in the comments). Otherwise, the function is changing the argument but not the variable passed to the function. In order to change the variable, you have to de-reference the argument, so its type has to be either a pointer or a reference to the variable type. Since the type of the variable is `T*`, the argument type should be `T**` or `T*&`